# Can a moment generating function for the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution be found?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

Can a moment generating function for the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution curve be found and would it be useful for the analysis of the Boltzmann distribution curve?

Comment: In find the question not clear at all. What do you mean by "Boltzmann distribution curve"? The Boltzmann distribution is a probability measure on the set of microstates. And your moment generating function is supposed to generate the moments of which random variable?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the [Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) ?

Comment: Yes, so sorry that I conflated the two, I meant Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution

Comment: This is a [Chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) with 3 degrees of freedom. Its moment generating function can be found in the Wikipedia article.